# ios - how to set global styles?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am working with a storyboard, and I have some pages on the app that have content.  Instead of manually creating styles for headings, and texts by using the right side of the screen little color/font editor, is there a way to just create a single style and use it throughout those content pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want this to affect all labels or just some of them? If its all of then you could use the UIAppearance protocol.

Comment: @CleverError I would just like to affect some of the labels...just in the same manner a stylesheet would in an html site.

Comment: This library looks like a good solution: https://github.com/tombenner/nui (I haven't tested it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, but it would require you to use a stylesheet framework.

For example, three20 has a TTStyle framework, which is really good at creating style classes that you can apply to labels, buttons, and views.

http://three20.info/

Check out this tutorial:
http://www.mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial

I believe Nimbus Kit also has a style library, but I have not explored it as much:

http://nimbuskit.info/

Comment: so you mean I have to use a 3rd party library? There is no way to do this in the standard package?

Comment: You could sub-class a label, implement your own style drawing code, and then use that class. But my personal feeling is that the Three20 stuff is way better. For example, you can combine an inner-shadow, multiple borders, gradients, rounded corners, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want the styles to affect some of your labels, I would suggest creating a subclass of `UILabel` for each different style you want. In each subclass, implement the `awakefromNib` method to set the style properties of the label. Then, for each label you want to have the style applied to, set the class in interface builder to be your subclass

[image]

Comment: Just saw this before I posted comment above - yeah this works too.